# I am trying to make adc driver for avr atmega 32

Tags: c, embedded

I get this error:

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

when I try to do the same 2 lines in my `adc.c` but when I do it in my main file they run without a problem.

Lines are:

```
config.prescaler = ADC_prescaler_8;
config.ref_volt = ADC_internal_2;
```

Here's the `adc.h` file:

```
/*
 * adc.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2024
 *      Author: admin
 */
#include "std_types.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#ifndef ADC_H_
#define ADC_H_

typedef enum {
    ADC_aREF , ADC_aVCC, ADC_internal_2=3
}ADC_refVoltage;



typedef enum {
    ADC_prescaler_2=1,ADC_prescaler_4,ADC_prescaler_8,ADC_prescaler_16,ADC_prescaler_32
    ,ADC_prescaler_64,ADC_prescaler_128
}ADC_prescaler;



typedef struct{
    ADC_refVoltage ref_volt;
    ADC_prescaler prescaler;
}ADC_configType;

void ADC_init(const ADC_configType * ptr);


uint16 ADC_readChannel(uint8 channel);




#endif /* ADC_H_ */
```

Here's the `adc.c` file:

```
/*
 * adc.c
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2024
 *      Author: admin
 */
#include "adc.h"
#include "common_macros.h"

   ADC_configType config;
   config.prescaler = ADC_prescaler_8;    //I get the error on those lines
   config.ref_volt = ADC_internal_2;

void ADC_init(const ADC_configType *ptr){
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADEN);
    ADCSRA = ((ADCSRA)&(0xF8)) | (ptr -> prescaler & 0x07);
    ADMUX =  ((ADMUX) &(0x3F)) | (ptr -> ref_volt<<REFS0);
    CLEAR_BIT(ADCSRA,ADIE);
}




uint16 ADC_readChannel(uint8 channel){

        ADMUX = (ADMUX&(0xE0))|(channel&(0x07));
        SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADSC);
        while(BIT_IS_CLEAR(ADCSRA,ADIF));
        SET_BIT(ADCSRA,ADIF);
        return ADC;
}
```

Comment: These two lines are outside of any execution context (not in a any function). Move them into a function that is supposed to execute them. Or, if you want to *initialize* the structure `config`, then use `struct` initialization syntax (look it up).

Comment: Perhaps `ADC_configType config = { ADC_internal_2, ADC_prescaler_8 };`

Comment: `config` is unused in this code.  You could simply delete those lines.

Answer (score 0):

The config should look rather like this:

```
// only since C99
const Adc_ConfigType Adc_Config = {
    .prescaler = ADC_prescaler_8,
    .ref_volt = ADC_internal_2,
};

// or pre-C99
const Adc_ConfigType Adc_Config = {
    /* .. maybe other struct members depending on Adc_ConfigType declaration .. */
    /* .prescaler = */ ADC_prescaler_8,
    /* .ref_volt  = */ ADC_internal_2,
};

void main(void) {
    Adc_Init(&Adc_Config);
}
```

Comment: The `.` syntax avoids getting them the wrong way round in your other example.